# Неправильно срабатывает анимация персонажа в unity

Tags: unity3d

По видеоуроку сделал анимацию персонажа 2D и пытаюсь применить эти анимации при движениях персонажа. Движение осуществляется через UI кнопки посредством EventTrigger и событий PointerDown и PointerUP.

Создал перечисление как указано в уроке, где идут сами анимации и пытаюсь их применить при движениях персонажа. Но есть проблемы с анимацией при движении персонажа. Например когда игрок идет вправо (выполняется метод ForwardButtonDown) вначале игрок вроде бы анимируется как нужно т.е. идет анимация Run, но через несколько движений как будто он прыгает, хотя я продолжаю нажимать кнопку вправо (вперед для 2D персонажа).

Вот полностью скрипт.. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать анимации в коде

```
public class CharacterScript : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private int lives = 5; //кол-во жизней

    [SerializeField]
    private float speedX = 1.0F; //Скорость игрока

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpForce = 15.0F; 

    [SerializeField]
    private float horizontalSpeed;

    new private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    private Animator animator;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;

    private bool isGrounded;

    private PlayerState State {
        get {
            return (PlayerState) animator.GetInteger("State");
        }

        set {
            animator.SetInteger("State", (int) value);
        }
    }

    private void Awake() {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void Start() { 
        speedX = 0; 
    }

    public void BackButtonDown() {
        speedX = -horizontalSpeed;
        sprite.flipX = true;
        if (isGrounded) {
            State = PlayerState.Run;
        }
    }

    public void ForwardButtonDown() {
        speedX = horizontalSpeed;
        sprite.flipX = false;
        if (isGrounded) {
            State = PlayerState.Run;
        }
    }

    public void BackOrForwardButtonUp() {
        speedX = 0;
        State = PlayerState.Idle;
    }

    public void UpButton() {
        if (isGrounded) {
            rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        transform.Translate(speedX, 0, 0);
        CheckGround();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            isGrounded = true;
            State = PlayerState.Idle;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            isGrounded = false;
            State = PlayerState.Jump;
        }
    }

    private void CheckGround() {
        Collider2D[] collides = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, 0.3F);

        isGrounded = collides.Length > 1;

        if (!isGrounded) {
            State = PlayerState.Jump;
        }
    }
}

public enum PlayerState {
    Idle,
    Run,
    Jump
}
```

Исходный вариант из урока

```
public class Character : Unit {

    [SerializeField]
    private int lives = 5; //кол-во жизней

    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 3.0F; //Скорость игрока

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpForce = 15.0F; //сила прыжка

    new private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    private Animator animator;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;

    private bool isGrounded = false;

    private PlayerState2 State {
        get {
            return (PlayerState2) animator.GetInteger("State");
        }

        set {
            animator.SetInteger("State", (int) value);
        }
    }

    private void Awake() {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        CheckGround();
    }

    void Update () {

        if (isGrounded) {
            State = PlayerState2.Idle;
        } 

        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal")) {
            Run();
        }

        if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical")) {
            Jump();
        }
    }


    public void Run() {
        //направление бега
        Vector3 direction = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + direction, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        sprite.flipX = direction.x < 0.0F;

        if (isGrounded) {
            State = PlayerState2.Run;
        }
    }

    public void Jump() {
        rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    private void CheckGround() {
        Collider2D[] collides = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, 0.3F);

        isGrounded = collides.Length > 1;

        if (!isGrounded) {
            State = PlayerState2.Jump;
        }
    }
}

public enum PlayerState2 {
    Idle,
    Run,
    Jump
}
```

Comment: посмотрите внимательно в свой аниматор. Есть подозрения, что у вас переходы между состояниями настроены на так как в уроке. Или состояния не циклятся а по выполнении переходят сразу в другое состояние

Comment: Анимации настроены точно также, проверял несколько раз. В уроке управление реализовывалось через клавиши клавиатуры, я решил переделать и реализовать через UI кнопки, но столкнулся с проблемой анимации.

Comment: @Kolhoznik, т.е. проблема есть только при использовании EventTrigger? При прямом перехвате Input-а из кода - всё нормально?

Comment: Да, в уроке код был немножко другой. Например был метод update, где анимации присваивались в зависимости от нажатия на клавиши. А в переделанном варианте я это убрал т.к. не знаю как прописать. В вопрос добавил исходный вариант скрипта из урока тоже

Comment: Первое: ещё раз посмотрите переход между анимациями, бывает по запарке везде поставишь переход анимации равно, а в одном месте больше или меньше и поэтому две анимации запускаются и "дергается".

Comment: Второе: сохраняйте текущее состояние, PlayerState curentState = PlayerState.Idle перед сменой state делайте проверку и меняйте значение только если значение меняется, например, if(curentState !=PlayerState.Run){State = PlayerState.Run; curentState !=PlayerState.Run}. Т.к. при переопределении State (даже если было такое же значение) может срабатывать переход (зависит от того, как у вас в контроллере переходы выставлены) и та же анимация запускаться заново, и получается дерганье (у меня в unity5 было такое).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую вечером когда доберусь до компа.